# Woocommerce Product Addons Filter Addon's by value

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce, hook

I have a product on my site that allows users to select what items they would like included with their order from a list of product addons. The default is 0 and the user can input any number to include that addon in their order.

I'm using the following code to successfully filter out all addons with a value of 0 from the shopping cart and the order confirmation page. But I cannot figure out how to filter them out of the order details in the admin area or from the admin and customer emails. Hoping someone here will have some answers/direction for me.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'custom_order_items', 10, 2 );


function custom_order_items( $order_meta ) {
    reset($order_meta);
    $first_key = key($order_meta);

    $search_term = 'Basket Items - ';
    $order = reset($order_meta);

    if( is_array($order['item_meta']) ) {

        foreach ( $order['item_meta'] as $key => $value ) {
            if (strpos($key, $search_term) !== false && $value[0] == 0) {
                unset($order['item_meta'][$key]);
            }
        }


        $order_meta[$first_key] = $order;

    }

    return $order_meta;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying dozens of Woocommerce filters I finally figured out a solution to this problem. By filtering the product array when adding products to the cart I was able to successfully filter out addons that had a value of 0.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'custom_function', 10, 2 );

function custom_function( $item ) {
    $addons = $item['addons'];

    foreach( $addons as $key => $value) {
        if( $value['value'] === 0 ) {
            unset($addons[$key]);
        }
    }

    $item['addons'] = $addons;

    return $item;
}
```